# how to serve (start of the rally) prediction in table tennis

Tags: rules, tennis, table-tennis, serve

I am working on a problem where I need to find the moment of service (start of the rally) in a table tennis game.

> start and end of a rally in a game - the moment when a player serves the ball and the moment when the exchange of the shots between players is finished, i.e. one of the players scores a point or the rally stops for any other reason

I have the coordinates of the ball in the game, and I am writing a program to identify this moment based on the coordinates of the ball.

What exactly would identify this moment, to match the definition in the rules?

Comment: We've discussed making this question on-topic by focusing on the sport aspects, rules and technical points, rather than about the physics and programming. If you're unhappy with the edits, feel free to correct them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serve in table tennis is performed by making the ball go directly upwards from the flat hand, or as close to vertically as a human athlete can achieve, allowed to move ballistically for a short time, then struck with the paddle.

You are looking for a consecutive sequence of short periods, consisting of

1. small amount of acceleration, almost perfectly vertical
2. short time of ballistic flight
3. large spike of acceleration, almost entirely horizontal
4. slightly longer time of ballistic flight

Tennis (lawn tennis, outdoor tennis) is very similar, though the ball is thrown further and got harder, so the distances and accelerations will be much larger.

Once you have found this sequence, you can identify the spike of horizontal acceleration as the moment of the serve.

For details on the modelling and programming aspects of this identification, you can refer to the Mathematics and/or Physics Stack Exchange sites, and Stack Overflow.